# How to combine the dictionaries in python

Tags: python, django

I have 2 dictionaries

```
dict1 = {'color': {'attri': ['Black']}, 'diameter': {'attri': ['(300, 600)']}}

dict2 = {'size': {'op':'in'}, 'diameter': {'op':'range'}, 'color': {'op':'in'}}
```

I want to combine the 2 dictionaries such that

```
dict3 = {'color': {'op': 'in', 'attri': ['Black']}, 'diameter': {'op': 'range', 'attri': ['(300,600)']}}
```

Comment: check this link answer is already there  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: @ashishpal That's not the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a mix of `dict comprehensions` and `dict unpacking`:

```
dict1 = {'color': {'attri':['Black']}, 'diameter': {'attri':['(300, 600)']}}
dict2 = {'size': {'op':'in'}, 'diameter': {'op':'range'}, 'color': {'op':'in'}}

dict3 = {n:{**dict1[n],**dict2[n]} for n in dict1}
```

Comment: Thanks This is working, How can I also do this if  dict1 = {'color': ['Black'], 'diameter': ['(300, 600)']}

Comment: @AakashPatel What should happen then?

Comment: I am getting the following error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AAKASH PATEL/Desktop/demo1.py", line 4, in <module>
    dict3 = {n:{**dict1[n],**dict2[n]} for n in dict1}
  File "C:/Users/AAKASH PATEL/Desktop/demo1.py", line 4, in <dictcomp>
    dict3 = {n:{**dict1[n],**dict2[n]} for n in dict1}
TypeError: 'list' object is not a mapping

Comment: @AakashPatel Yes, because `list` can't be unpacked like that. It doesn't make sense to transform a `list` to a `dict`. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 6):

This method uses a `defaultdict` and is safe even if a key only appears in one of the dictionaries.

```
import itertools
import collections

dict3 = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for key, value in itertools.chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
     dict3[key].update(value)
```

---

Proof -- applied to:

```
dict1 = {'color': {'attri':['Black']}, 'diameter': {'attri':['(300, 600)']}}
dict2 = {'size': {'op':'in'}, 'diameter': {'op':'range'}, 'color': {'op':'in'}}
```

the output of `dict(dict3)` is:

```
{'color': {'attri': ['Black'], 'op': 'in'},
'diameter': {'attri': ['(300, 600)'], 'op': 'range'},
'size': {'op': 'in'}}
```

---

Although looking at your expected output, you only want a result if the key appears in both dictionaries, in which case I'd do:

```
dict3 = {key: {**dict1[key], **dict2[key]} 
         for key in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
res = {}
for item in dict1:
  res.setdefault(item, {})
  res[item].update(dict1[item])
  if item in dict2:
    res[item].update(dict2[item])
```

Comment: Thanks This is working, How can I also do this if dict1 = {'color': ['Black'], 'diameter': ['(300, 600)']}

Answer (score -1):

For dictionaries x and y, z becomes a merged dictionary with values from y and from x.

In Python 3.5 or greater, :

```
z = {**x, **y}
```

In Python 2, (or 3.4 or lower) write a function:

```
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()   # start with x's keys and values
    z.update(y)    # modifies z with y's keys and values & returns None
    return z
and

z = merge_two_dicts(x, y)
```

Comment: This isn't what OP wants. Look at the expected result of `dict3`.